# How to see who created the record?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

How to see who created the record?

For example,

```
"Contact" model=res.partner
```

In Odoo I can't find where such data is stored

Comment: Use [create_uid](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/models.py#L3069) field to see who created the record.

Comment: Kenly, ok. I thought it was already somewhere in the user interface

Comment: It's sometimes visible in the chat(ter) of a record or in the records meta data which can be looked into when the client debug mode is activated.

Answer (score 1):

There are various places to look:

1) If you have database access, you can look at: create_uid and create_date.

```
SELECT id,create_uid,create_date FROM table_name;
```

2) If you go into debug mode, i.e. https://yourdatabase.odoo.com/web?debug=true then in the debug menu you choose "View Metadata"

[image]

[image]

3) Like [@CZoellner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3146213/czoellner) suggested, the chatter will show this if it is enabled on the model and view. The image below shows OdooBot created 7 days ago for example.

[image]